# CircuitPython library usb_midi not found

Tags: python, pip, usb, midi, adafruit-circuitpython

I am making a project with midi. I have installed circuit python using the following article https://gallaugher.com/makersnack-installing-circuitpython-on-a-raspberry-pi/

When I try to import usb_midi I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'usb_midi'
```

Im pretty sure I have installed circuit python correctly as I can import board, digitalio, etc. I can also successfully import adafruit_midi.

Answer (score 0):

I belive usb_midi is included in Circuitpython, you should be able to import it like

```
import usb_midi
```

at the top of your file

Comment: If you are saying that's a standard library with CircuitPython, I don't think that's true. Otherwise, how could the OP even get that error? That's a CP error!

I am running into this same issue, myself. I already added adafruit-circuitpython-midi) (1.2.1) but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Did you install adafruit_midi ?

check this tutorial
https://learn.adafruit.com/grand-central-usb-midi-controller-in-circuitpython/code-usb-midi-in-circuitpython